# Error while calling objective C method inside audioRouteChangeListenerCallback method

Tags: ios, xcode

I used this code to check if something plugged in or out in audiojack of my iphone

```
    void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID inPropertyID, UInt32 inPropertyValueSize, const void *inPropertyValue ) {
        // ensure that this callback was invoked for a route change
        if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;

        {
            // Determines the reason for the route change, to ensure that it is not
            //      because of a category change.
            CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = (CFDictionaryRef)inPropertyValue;

            CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue (routeChangeDictionary, CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason) );
            SInt32 routeChangeReason;
            CFNumberGetValue (routeChangeReasonRef, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &routeChangeReason);

            if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable) {
                  //Handle Headset Unplugged
                NSLog(@"PluggedOut");


            }
            else if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_NewDeviceAvailable)
            {
                //Handle Headset plugged in
                NSLog(@"Something Plugged In");
            }

}
```

but when I add my objective C method (which works perfect in all other codes) to determine if the plugged device was my card reader it endup with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error what I tried was the code below

```
else if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_NewDeviceAvailable)
                    {
                        //Handle Headset plugged in
                        NSLog(@"Something Plugged In");
  audiotest *test;
            if([test Checkheadphonestatus] == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Your iPosReader Connected");
            }
            else if([test Checkheadphonestatus] == 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"Connected device was not iPos Reader");
            }
                    }

        }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
audiotest *test;
```

Looks like you have not initialized `test`.  Try replacing it with:

```
audiotest *test = [[audiotest alloc] init];
```

Also as a side note, it's an Objective-C convention to PascalCase your class names and camelCase your method names. For example:

```
AudioTest *test = [[AudioTest alloc] init];
int status = [test checkHeadphoneStatus];
```

Comment: Yes the error was since the I didn't initialize, But now [test checkHeadphoneStatus] always returning 0! Wat may be the issue?

Comment: Either you have a bug in `checkHeadphoneStatus` or somehow `test` is set to `nil` which is a like NULL/nullptr in c/c++ except that it always return 0 on whatever method you call on it.  Check to make sure your `init` method is working properly.  If it's a bug in `checkHeadphoneStatus` your on your own.